# Add a numbered list column to a returned MySQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am trying to get a sequential number column returned with my sql query. I need this to be inside the SELECT statement because I want to nest this query in another, and then use the column generated before for some further calculations.

I have looked everywhere and I can't find any examples of this.

Something to the effect of the following:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() as row_number from my_awesome_table;
```

This should generate something like this:

```
row_number some_column some_other_column
---------- ----------- -----------------
    1        bla bla      bla bla bla 
    2        bla bla      bla bla bla 
    3        bla bla      bla bla bla 
    4        bla bla      bla bla bla
```

Note that some_column and some_other_column are real existing columns in my_awesome_table, whereas row_number is generated on-the-fly for this query only.

Thanks!
swine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [MySQL user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Let us take a variable `t1`. Initialize it at `0`. And increment it in every select value.

```
SET @t1=0;
SELECT @t1 := @t1+1 as row_number, my_awesome_table.* from my_awesome_table
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't work with PHP's mysql_query(). Apparently you can't use multiple queries, and thus can't do the SET @t1=0; Any way around this?

Comment: @swinefeaster my answer actually has a way around that, as well as a warning which you should take heed of.

Comment: @swinefeaster, try two mysql_query statements. First with only `SET` statement and immediately next mysql_query with the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: You're welcome. You should have tagged it with `PHP` if you wanted PHP code.

Comment: I think I did (unless you just added it)

Comment: i have another question for you... in my real-world sql query, i had to wrap it with another select query to get at some of the fields in a table i was doing a natural join with. however, this seems to obliterate the row column...

Comment: should i post another question or can i send you the sql query directly?

Comment: ok i posted another question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826240/bubbling-up-columns-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to do what several other people have suggested is this:

```
SELECT @rownum := (IFNULL(@rownum, 0) + 1), my_awesome_table.*
FROM my_awesome_table
```

**You should be careful using user variables in your SELECT, though** -   As [the docs note](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html),

> "In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate
>   @a first and then do an assignment
>   second. However, changing the
>   statement (for example, by adding a
>   GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause)
>   may cause MySQL to select an execution
>   plan with a different order of
>   evaluation."

Different versions of MySQL may produce different results.  Test accordingly, and consider numbering your rows in your code, rather than in the query.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in my real world case, as added above :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @rownum = @rownum + 1 AS row_number, mat.*
      FROM my_awesome_table mat, 
           (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL don't do that.

A little googling found this article:

http://explainextended.com/2009/09/14/mysql-emulating-row_number-with-multiple-order-by-conditions/