# Bubbling Up Columns in Sql

Tags: sql, mysql

Pardon the convoluted example, but I believe there is something fundamental about sql I am missing and I'm not sure what it is. I have this crazy query...

`SELECT * 
  FROM (
  SELECT * 
    FROM (
    SELECT @t1 := @t1 +1 AS leaderboard_entry_youngness_rank, 1 - @t1 /100 AS
       leaderboard_entry_youngness_based_on_expiry, leaderboard_entry . * , 
       NOW( ) - leaderboard_entry_timestamp AS leaderboard_entry_age_in_some_units, 
       TO_DAYS( NOW( ) ) - TO_DAYS( leaderboard_entry_timestamp ) 
         AS leaderboard_entry_age_in_days
    FROM leaderboard_entry) AS inner_temp
    NATURAL JOIN leaderboard
    NATURAL JOIN user
    WHERE (
    leaderboard_load_key =  'sk-en-adjectives-1'
    OR leaderboard_load_key =  '-sk-en-adjectives-1'
    )
    AND leaderboard_quiz_mode =  '0'
    ORDER BY leaderboard_entry_age_in_some_units ASC , leaderboard_entry_timestamp ASC 
    LIMIT 0 , 100
  ) AS outer_temp
ORDER BY leaderboard_entry_elapsed_time_ms ASC , leaderboard_entry_timestamp ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 50`

I added the second nested SELECT statement because the user_name in the user table was not being returned in the outermost query. But now the leaderboard_entry_youngness_based_on_expiry field, which is being generated based on a row index ratio, is not working correctly.

If I remove the second nested SELECT statement, the leaderboard_entry_youngness_based_on_expiry works as expected, but the user_name column is not returned.

How can I satisfy both? Why is this happening?

Thanks!

This stems from the following question:

[Add a numbered list column to a returned MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819835/add-a-numbered-list-column-to-a-returned-mysql-query)

Comment: Where is the `user_name` column coming from? is it possible its in more than 1 table?

Comment: The user_name column is coming from the user table, and nope it's not in multiple tables :(

Comment: did you make sure to set the `@t1` session variable to 0 each time before running the query?

Comment: Sorry the "set @t1=0;" is in a previous query. I had to split it out because I use the query in PHP mysql_query()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner SELECT statement, you do not have `user.user_name`, that's why username is not returned. Remove the outer query, do it like earlier but with `user.user_name` like this:

```
....
SELECT @t1 := @t1 +1 AS leaderboard_entry_youngness_rank, 1 - @t1 /100 AS
   leaderboard_entry_youngness_based_on_expiry, leaderboard_entry . * , 
   NOW( ) - leaderboard_entry_timestamp AS leaderboard_entry_age_in_some_units, 
   TO_DAYS( NOW( ) ) - TO_DAYS( leaderboard_entry_timestamp ) 
     AS leaderboard_entry_age_in_days, user.user_name

....
```

Comment: awesome that works! is there any way i can do user.* to get all the other columns in that table as well? or should i list them out one by one? or in general is it better to list them one by one?

Comment: You can do `user.*`. Just replace `user.user_name` with `user.*`.

Comment: it doesn't like that. it says there's a duplicate column user_id ( that's the one i'm natural joining user and leaderboard_entry with)

Comment: Then you need to list them one by one like `user.user_name, user.user_address, ...`

Comment: Hey I have another easy one for you! Sorry I'm a c++/java/c# dev, not so good at the db stuffs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835468/distinct-in-complex-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `ORDER BY` in the inner most query, since there currently is no `ORDER BY` clause, its wrong to say that "is not working correctly".

Check if you take away the outer `SELECT * FROM...`, see if there are duplicate `user_name` columns.

BTW, Since you are not using the row index columns in your query, why not just put this logic in the application itself? it will be more reliable doing so.

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood. There is nothing wrong with the order. There are no duplicate user_name columns. The only problem is that the user_name column, among others, is not bubbling up to the resulting query.

Comment: I can't put the row indexes in the application itself because I want them generated by timestamp, which will become the "age" of the rows, and then resort by elapsed time, keeping the original row indexes as column fields for display in the app

Comment: @swinefeaster Sorry, lets start over :-). Can you please post the table definitions for the `leaderboard_entry`, `leaderboard` and `user` tables?